# TypeError when loading in Keras model

Tags: python, keras, typeerror

I've defined a model using the MobileNet architecture from keras using the code below:

```
model = MobileNet(input_shape=(size, size, 1), alpha=1.0, weights=None, classes=NCATS)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.002), loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[categorical_crossentropy, categorical_accuracy, top_3_accuracy])
```

After training, I saved the model the using

```
model.save(MOD1_PATH)
```

I am now trying to load in the model using

```
model = load_model(MOD1_PATH)
```

but I am getting the following TypeError when trying to load it:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-2166dee60e7c> in <module>
----> 1 load_model(MOD1_PATH)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    418     f = H5Dict(filepath, 'r')
    419     try:
--> 420         model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
    421     finally:
    422         if opened_new_file:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/saving.py in _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
    224         raise ValueError('No model found in config.')
    225     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
--> 226     model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    227     model_weights_group = f['model_weights']
    228 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/saving.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
    457                         '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
    458     from ..layers import deserialize
--> 459     return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    460 
    461 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/layers/__init__.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     53                                     module_objects=globs,
     54                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 55                                     printable_module_name='layer')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    143                     config['config'],
    144                     custom_objects=dict(list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 145                                         list(custom_objects.items())))
    146             with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    147                 return cls.from_config(config['config'])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/network.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
   1020         # First, we create all layers and enqueue nodes to be processed
   1021         for layer_data in config['layers']:
-> 1022             process_layer(layer_data)
   1023         # Then we process nodes in order of layer depth.
   1024         # Nodes that cannot yet be processed (if the inbound node

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/network.py in process_layer(layer_data)
   1006 
   1007             layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data,
-> 1008                                       custom_objects=custom_objects)
   1009             created_layers[layer_name] = layer
   1010 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/layers/__init__.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     53                                     module_objects=globs,
     54                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 55                                     printable_module_name='layer')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    145                                         list(custom_objects.items())))
    146             with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
--> 147                 return cls.from_config(config['config'])
    148         else:
    149             # Then `cls` may be a function returning a class.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/base_layer.py in from_config(cls, config)
   1107             A layer instance.
   1108         """
-> 1109         return cls(**config)
   1110 
   1111     def count_params(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py in __init__(self, max_value, negative_slope, threshold, **kwargs)
    290                  threshold=0., **kwargs):
    291         super(ReLU, self).__init__(**kwargs)
--> 292         if max_value is not None and max_value < 0.:
    293             raise ValueError('max_value of ReLU layer '
    294                              'cannot be negative value: %s' % str(max_value))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'
```

Has anyone run into this kind of problem loading a trained model before? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried loading the model using different versions of keras and also tried tf.keras to load it but none of them seem to be working. The model was saved using keras 2.2.4 if that is any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with:

*Tensorflow* **1.11.0**,

*Keras* **2.1.6-tf**

I created a notebook in Google Colaboratory and the result was the same.
Google colaboratory configuration:

*Tensorflow* **1.12.0-rc1**,

*Keras* **2.1.6-tf**

Then I tryied to `load_model` with:

*Tensorflow* **1.9.0**,

*Keras* **2.1.6-tf**

and everything began to work.
May be this is a bug with new versions of *Tensorflow*